# Extract the minimum value from a string when there are more than 1 numbers in that string

Tags: r, regex

I have a serious of strings that contain numbers. Some of these string contain 2 numbers like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(x ="Want to extract both values 7 + 8",
                  y = "var")
```

I am interested in the smallest number from that string but am having trouble extracting because I keep ending up in a list-column and don't really know how to proceed. My ideal output would be something like:

```
> df1
                                  x   y comp_num  firstnum  secondnum
1 Want to extract both values 7 + 8 var     7, 8         7          8
```

Here is how I am extracting the number:

```
df1$comp_num = regmatches(df1$x,gregexpr('[0-9]+',df1$x))
```

But then I end up with a list column. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
df1$unnestval <- tidyr::unnest(df1$comp_num)

df1$separ <- tidyr::separate(df1$comp_num)

df1$unlistval <- unlist(df1$comp_num)
```

The problem I am having is with the list column but only because that is where my approach ended up. The central question is how to extract the minimum value from a string when there are more than 1 numbers in that string AND output that numbers as a column in dataframe.

Comment: `df1$comp_num = min(unlist(regmatches(df1$x,gregexpr('[0-9]+',df1$x))))`

Comment: Fwiw, your usage of unnest is wrong. It needs two args: both the data set and the column, something like `tidyr::unnest(df1, comp_num)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help if you are willing to switch to `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(C1=replicate(5, paste0(sample(LETTERS, 2), sample(1:9,2), collapse = "")))
DT
     C1
1: Y7J6
2: J8O5
3: M4G6
4: I5Q9
5: T3M1

## Extracting Digits
DT[ , C2:=lapply(C1, function(x){ gsub("[^\\d]", "", x, perl = T) }), by=C1]

## Extracting Min Value
DT[, C3:=lapply(C2, function(x){min(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))))}), by=C1]

## Extracting Max Value
DT[, C4:=lapply(C2, function(x){max(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))))}), by=C1]
DT
     C1 C2 C3 C4
1: Y7J6 76  6  7
2: J8O5 85  5  8
3: M4G6 46  4  6
4: I5Q9 59  5  9
5: T3M1 31  1  3
```

Notice that the regular expression `[^\\d]` is matching all non-digits in a string.